# Compact way to write the probability of an alert being generated

Tags: probability

**Case with one event**

Let there be a single underlying event $a$ that occurs, that generates an alert, $y=1$, with probability $p$. Let the alert also be generated randomly (independently of $a$ occurring) with probability $f$. The probability that we see an alert, if $a$ occurs, in this case is
\begin{align}
P(y=1|a=1) &= pf + p(1-f) + (1-p)f\\
&= p + (1-p)f
\end{align}
where the alert could be generated by $a$ *and* randomly w.p. $pf$; generated by $a$ and not randomly w.p. $p(1-f)$; or not generated by $a$ but instead only randomly with probability $(1-p)f$. This reduces to $p + (1-p)f$.

**Case with two events**

Generalizing this to two events, $a$ and $b$, that can both generate $y=1$, with probabilities $p$ and $q$, respectively, plus allowing for the alert to occurring randomly w.p. $f$ results in the probability (if both $a$ and $b$ occur)
\begin{align}
P(y=1|a=1,b=1) = pq + p(1-q) + (1-p)q + (1-p)(1-q)f
\end{align}
where I've skipped to the reduced form described in the first case.

**Case with $n$ events**

How do I write this compactly for the case where there are $n$ events (also allowing for the alert to be randomly enabled w.p. $f$)? Is there a way to write the expression using sums and products?

Comment: Idea: Observe that $1-(1-p)(1-f)=1-(1-p-f+pf)=p+f-fp$ which is what you calculated in the case with one event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the "alert events", including the "background" event, are independent, then the probability that there is no alert is
$$(1-p_1)\cdots(1-p_n)(1-f)$$
and what you want is the complement of this,
$$1-(1-p_1)\cdots(1-p_n)(1-f)\ .$$